# C# problemas con. Replace() en una hoja de excel

Tags: c#, excel

Estoy tratando de remover las comas de una celda dentro de un archivo de excel, pero tengo la situación de que tras aplicar mi código en la primera fila todo bien no tengo ningún problema, pero a partir de la segunda vuelta mi código se detiene por completo en la misma linea de donde aplico el `Replace()`.
No me manda un error , simplemente se congela y se queda cargando para siempre.
La variable `x13` la uso para saber que si el método remueve las comas y en efecto todo sale bien, hasta la siguiente vuelta del `for`.

```
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePatht);
Worksheet x = excel.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;
_Worksheet xlWorksheet = sheet.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
for (int ix = 12; ix < rowCount; ix++) {

  //xlRange.NumberFormat = "0.00";

  xlRange.Cells[ix, 2].Replace(",", " ");
  var x13 = xlRange.Cells[ix, 2].Text;
  xlRange.Cells[ix, 4].NumberFormat = "0.00";
  xlRange.Cells[ix, 5].NumberFormat = "0.00";
  xlRange.Cells[ix, 6].NumberFormat = "0.00";
}

sheet.Save();
```

Aquí les dejo una imagen de la celda que estoy tratando de modificar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con esto: xlRange.Cells[ix, 2].Value = xlRange.Cells[ix, 2].Text.Replace(",", " ");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok lo resolví de esta forma, si alguien tiene una mejor u alguna observación, es bienvenido a postearla.

```
for (int ix = 12; ix <= rowCount; ix++) {


  var x12 = xlRange.Cells[ix, 2].Text;
  x12 = x12.Replace(",", " ");
  xlRange.Cells[ix, 2].Value = x12;
  var x13 = xlRange.Cells[ix, 2].Text;
  xlRange.Cells[ix, 4].NumberFormat = "0.00";
  xlRange.Cells[ix, 5].NumberFormat = "0.00";
  xlRange.Cells[ix, 6].NumberFormat = "0.00";


}
```